# How to do a full match of a string using regex within a document to make modifications of everything after the word

Tags: regex, awk, sed, match

I have a file that looks like this called listofnames.txt.

```
this-is-name-1
this-is-name-2
...
this-is-name-11
this-is-name-12
this-is-name-13
this-is-name-14
...
this-is-name-21
....
```

I want to do a full match of a certain word and add a "0" next to it. I use the following command:

`sed -i '/\bthis-is-name-1\b/s/$/ 0/' listofnames.txt`

```
this-is-name-1 0
this-is-name-2
...
this-is-name-11
this-is-name-12
this-is-name-13
this-is-name-14
...
this-is-name-21
....
```

But after that I want to be able to replace everything in the line after the word and replace it with a 1 to make it look like this

```
this-is-name-1 1
this-is-name-2
...
this-is-name-11
this-is-name-12
this-is-name-13
this-is-name-14
...
this-is-name-21
....
```

I use the following command,
`sed -i '/\bthis-is-name-1\b/s/$/ 1/' listofnames.txt`
but I get this,

```
this-is-name-1 0 1 
this-is-name-2
...
this-is-name-11
this-is-name-12
this-is-name-13
this-is-name-14
...
this-is-name-21
....
```

How do I fix the code, what's the right command for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative `gnu-awk` command that would work in both conditions and save changes inline.

```
# place 0 in the end
awk -i inplace -v n='0' -v s='this-is-name-1' '$1 == s { $2 = n } 1' file

# place 1 in the end
awk -i inplace -v n='1' -v s='this-is-name-1' '$1 == s { $2 = n } 1' file
```

---

Run this in python:

```
import subprocess

currentname = 'this-is-name-1'
argList = ["awk", "-i", "inplace", "-v", "n=1", "-v", "s=" + currentname, '$1 == s{$2 = n} 1', 'file']

subprocess.call(argList)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221448/discussion-between-anarchy-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, in case you are ok with `awk`. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. Also your shell variable shouldn't have spaces while assigning to it.

```
currentname='this-is-name-1'
awk -v str="$currentname" '$0 ~ "^"str"$"{print $0,1;next} 1' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v str="$currentname" '    ##Starting awk program from here and setting variable str value to shell variable currentname here.
$0 ~ "^"str"$"{                ##Checking if line starts with str and ends with it.
  print $0,1                   ##Printing current line and 1 here.(change 0 to get 0 printed here)
  next                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                              ##1 will print edited/non-edited lines here.
' Input_file                   ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: can you help me modify the first part to use awk instead of sed as well then?, what's the replace file flag like sed has -i

Comment: @anarchy, you mean you want to `0` separate output and `1` separate output right? If this is the case then for getting `0` use `awk -v str="$currentname" 'match($0,"^"str"$"){print $0,0;next} 1' Input_file` and let me know in case of any queries.